# Equivalence of the Two Definitions of Norm of Dual Space

Tags: functional-analysis

The dual space of a normed linear space $V$ is the space of all linear bounded functional on $V$:

$$
V^*:=\{f:V\to R\mid\text{$f$ is linear and bounded}\}
$$
The norm of $V^*$ is defined as:
$$
\|f\|=\sup_{\|u\| \leq 1} |f(u)| \tag{1}
$$

Can you explain to me why (1) is equivalence to the definition:
$$
\|f\|=\sup \frac{|f(u)|}{\|u\|}
$$

I tried to work this out myself but I could only show the equivalence when the $\|u\| \leq 1$ in (1) is changed into $\|u\|=1$.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linearity, $\frac{|f(u)|}{\|u\|} = |f(\frac{u}{\|u\|})|$ so that's one direction, that is (2) (the 2nd def) is $\leq (1)$. The other direction follows from the fact that if $\|u\|\leq 1$, then $|f(u)| \leq \frac{|f(u)|}{\|u\|}$

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why (2) < (1)?

Comment: Let $v = \frac{u}{||u||}$. Then $||v|| = 1$ and you're taking a larger sup, indeed for $||v||\leq 1$.

Comment: I completely understand the proof now. However, I am still having trouble seeing the "image" of the proof. In fact, I have this same problem whenever a proof on equality of two quantities involving proving each side is smaller or equal (or larger or equal) to the other. Do you think you can explain a bit more to me how this particular proof works?

Comment: I dont know what you mean, but if $a\leq b\leq a$, then $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

When $\|u\|\lt 1$, define $v=\frac{u}{\|u\|}$  Let $c=\frac{1}{\|u\|}$.  Since the operator is linear $f(u)=cf(v)$, and $\frac{|f(u)|}{\|u\|}=\frac{c|f(v)|}{c\|v\|}$, where $\|v\|=1$.

Comment: If the typographical difference between $||u||$ and $\|u\|$ is not conspicuous to you, consider the difference between $\|u\|\|v\|,$ coded as `\|u\|\|v\|`, and $||u|| ||v||,$ coded as `||u|| ||v||`. I edited this answer accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @ureui : $\qquad\uparrow \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  I never noticed the difference!

Comment: @herbsteinberg In you answer, $cf(v)=\frac{1}{||u||}f(\frac{u}{||u||}) = f(\frac{u}{||u||^2}) \neq f(u)$ since $||u||<1$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @ASlowLearner Minor error $c=\|u\|$